# How to throttle file uploads from client side browser

Tags: asp.net, upload, bandwidth

15% of our branches are running on 128K connections and we have an asp.net application that allows users to upload files. Some of the files are large and we need to throttle or buffer the uploads to minimize network utilization.

Is there a way to throttle file uploads in an IE8 browser using javascript or other client side processing. We have a possible solution using Silverlight, but would like to use javascript.

Comment: I do not know of a way to control the client side behavior of the FileUpload control in that way.  I am guessing over a connection that small the only other thing you are running is terminal sessions.  I would suggest implementing network-level shaping based on protocol (class1 terminal traffic, class2 all other).  That way if the network link is upgraded, your HTTP traffic capacity will be naturally upgraded by the network team.  Otherwise you will have a web app that is bound by possibly outdated application-level bandwidth controls.

Comment: Branches are mostly terminal sessions. We have gone down the route to work with our network management team to find a solution, but the solution will take months to roll out.

Comment: Ouch.  There can't be much going on with those connections at only 128k apiece, even if you have a lot of branches that isn't much to add to router configs.  Sounds like you are stuck trying to solve a network-level problem with an application-level solution because your network team is unreasonably slow.  Hopefully someone on SO will know how to do some magic (happens daily!).

Answer (score 0):

Besides a network hardware solution, ISA Server, etc you can try the throttling in IIS. No - its not for uploads, but its for outgoing traffic, which one may be able to assume as a percentage of upload. I haven't tried this - but it may help.

http://www.44342.com/iis-f132-t18346-p1.htm

there is a plugin for *firefox* available - not sure about IE but it may put you on track:
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/755876